# How to implement "Hello World!" on the Internet in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following file for my package

```
package com.example.hello_app.demo

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class Hello {
        @RequestMapping("/")
        fun index() : String {
                return "Hello World"
        }
}
```

On running `gradle compileKotlin` I get the following errors

```
Unresolved reference: web
Unresolved reference: web
Unresolved reference: RestController
Unresolved reference: RequestMapping
```

What am I missing here?
I'm a begginer, so I'm so confused.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing here is the

> dependencies

.

You are using some classes which are not available in your project. I assume it's a spring boot project. It would be better if you start adding the dependencies in some `pom.xml` file or in some `buil.gradle` file.

Here is a sample example. how to add it to pom.xml of your project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.codejava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build> 

</project>
```

Read more [here](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example) or see docs [sample](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

please change the other details as per your project like name and package, id etc